# set report cache path not work in stimul

Tags: stimulsoft

My stimul cache size is too big its about 40G.

I want to change path of this cache so I do Like This:

```
Dim CacheFolder As String ="E:\StimulsoftReportsCache"

report1.ReportCachePath = CacheFolder

report1.ReportCacheMode = StiReportCacheMode.On

report1.RenderedPages.CanUseCacheMode = True

report1.RenderedPages.CacheMode = True

report1.RenderedPages.Clear()

'IN This Section Load Report On Report1

report1.Compile()
```

After That When I Compile Report `report1.ReportCachePath` change to `""`

I Dont Know Why It Change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the Cache path with next static method:

```
Stimulsoft.Report.StiOptions.Engine.ReportCache.CachePath
```